# How can I make this div the size of two divs subtracted from one another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/czra1qgu/ I don't know jquery/js so it's probably a syntax issue.

Markup:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"><div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.left {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    height: 100%;    
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $('.right').width($('.main').width(-$('.left').width()));
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.right').width($('.main').width(-$('.left').width()));
});
```

I also tried var foo = ('.left').width() then subtracting foo but it didn't work either.

Comment: Please mention what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @usmanali I want to have .right fill the rest of the div while .left has a fixed width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there. Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.right').width($('.main').width()-$('.left').width());
});
```

[width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) is a getter/setter. When you call `$('myElement').width()`, it will return the width as a unit-less value. Thats why you need `$('.main').width()`**-**`$('.left').width()`

Also, notice `document` is used instead of `window` for assigning the `ready` handler

> how can I further subtract pixels from .right?

```
var rightWidth = $('.right').width();
$('.right').css('width', (rightWidth - 10) + 'px');
```

Comment: @Ammar :) how can I further subtract pixels from .right?

Comment: It seems to glitch when .main's width has a decimal point (from resizing), is that fixable or no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `calc()` method:

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

```css
.main {
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.left {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    height: 100%;   
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"><div>
</div>
```